# Mock fails to install RPM dependency when building but can 'install' it

Tags: mocking, centos, rpm

I'm trying to build an RPM (target centos-6-x86_64) where the SPEC file contains a `BuildRequires` for `glibc-static.i686` (it's an old version of grub).  When I try to build using `mock...--rebuild <srpm>` I get an error indicating that the requirement for `glibc-static.i686` cannot be satisfied.

So I tried doing a `mock --init`, a `mock --install glibc-static.i686`, which worked, and then a `mock --no-clean...-rebuild <srpm>` which again failed.

So can someone explain how `mock` can find `glibc-static.i686` when doing an `--install` but not when doing the `--rebuild`?  Or perhaps suggest some diagnostics that I might enable to help me solve this?  I have carefully checked for typos ;-).

Comment: Could you provide some log output from `mock`? I have in mind the logs from the second `--rebuild` after `--install`